# get value from another id with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
function edt(dt){
  isi = $(".jml").val();
  alert(isi);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr>
  <td><input class="jml" id="edt1" value="1"/></td>
  <td><button id="edt1" onClick="edt(this.id);">btn 1</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><input class="jml" id="edt1" value="2"/></td>
  <td><button id="edt2" onClick="edt(this.id);">btn 2</button></td>
</tr>
```

i am trying to get value from  that have same id with the  which I've clicked.
at that script, eventhough I clicked btn 2, there was appear value of first 
please help me.. thanks!!

Comment: ID of an element must be unique

Comment: use class instead then use this context to point to click element

Comment: do you mean for the <input/> element @ArunPJohny?

Comment: @guradio, i don't understand.. please write me an example

Comment: Just pass this.value instead of this.id

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple issues in your code,

- Though you are passing the `id` to `edt` you are not using it
- `isi = $(".jml").val();` will always return the value of the first element with the class `jm1`

A more jQuery-ish solution will be is to

- use a jQuery event handler, use the class of the button to add a handler to all buttons
- in the handler you can use the `this` context to find the `input` element in the same row
- then read its value

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('.edt').click(function() {
    var isi = $(this).closest('tr').find('.jml').val();
    console.log('value: ' + isi)
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input class="jml" id="edt1" value="1" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <button class="edt">btn 1</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input class="jml" id="edt1" value="2" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <button class="edt">btn 2</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

If you can't use a jQuery event handler then

```
<button class="edt" onclick="edt(this)">btn 2</button>

function edt(el) {
  var isi = $(el).closest('tr').find('.jml').val();
  console.log('value: ' + isi)
}
```

```js
function edt(el) {
  var isi = $(el).closest('tr').find('.jml').val();
  console.log('value: ' + isi)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input class="jml" id="edt1" value="1" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <button class="edt" onclick="edt(this)">btn 1</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input class="jml" id="edt1" value="2" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <button class="edt" onclick="edt(this)">btn 2</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: using function please!! i can't using jQuery(function) click

Answer (score 1):

change your function. `ID must be unique [notice]` ,get id with prefix "#" .

```
function edt(dt){    
  isi = $("#"+dt).closest("tr").find(".jml").val();
  alert(isi);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('button').click(function() {

  alert($(this).closest('tr').find('input').val())

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input class="jml" class="edt1" value="1" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <button class="edt1">btn 1</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input class="jml" class="edt2" value="2" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <button class="edt2">btn 2</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Use `this context` and

[.closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)

> Description: For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree.

and

[.find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/)

> Description: Get the descendants of each element in the current set of matched elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element.

```
$(this)//clicked button
.closest('tr')//get the parent tr
.find('input')//get the input
.val()//get the value
```

```js
function edt(button) {


  alert($(button).closest('tr').find('input').val())


}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input class="jml" class="edt1" value="1" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <button class="edt1" onClick="edt(this);">btn 1</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input class="jml" class="edt2" value="2" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <button class="edt2" onClick="edt(this);">btn 2</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: using function please!! i can't using  click

Answer (score 0):

ID must be unique, but you're code can be better.

First, you're using `dt` as parameter into function, but it is never used. (Why?)

You can use it to read ID from element and give it to your script. Check this.

```js
function edt(dt){
  isi = $("#edt" + dt).val();
  alert(isi);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr>
  <td><input class="jml" id="edt1" value="1"/></td>
  <td><button onClick="edt(1);">btn 1</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><input class="jml" id="edt2" value="2"/></td>
  <td><button onClick="edt(2);">btn 2</button></td>
</tr>
```